# Configure MemSql for Google Cloud AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, singlestore, app-engine-flexible

Is there any handy option for running [MemSql](https://www.memsql.com/) on Google Cloud AppEngine and accessing it from dotnet application running on the same instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MemSql, but be aware that App Engine Flexible instances are restarted on a regular basis, and during that any locally saved data on disk will get lost, so hosting a database on Flexible is not a good choice. You may want to setup the DB on a GCE instance using persistent disk for storage.